# Rails Admin Eager loading relations for list view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading, rails-admin

We have a list view for a model `Ticket` in rails admin that loads very slowly.

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :crew
end
```

The reason it is slow is that we display the ticket's `crew` relation through a method `rails_admin_pretty_print` which accesses other related models.

```
class Crew < ActiveRecordBase
   belongs_to :pool
   belongs_to :leader

   def rails_admin_pretty_print
      "leader : #{leader.name} at time #{pool.datetime}"
   end
end
```

I want to eager load all of these objects in the initial query in order to speed up the request. Something like:

```
config.model "Ticket" do
   object_label_method :rails_admin_pretty_print
   list do
      field :crew, includes(:pool, :leader)
   end
end
```

I can't find any way to do this in the [rails admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki) docs. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Any better solution than one i answer?

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score -1):

If the `default_scope` of a model is set, Rails Admin uses it for the list view. Obviously it's not ideal (unless this is incredibly important and worth the workaround), but you could set your default scope in your `Crew` model as follows:

```
class Crew < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { includes(:pool, :leader) }

  # more crew stuff
end
```

Like I said, it's not ideal, because you'd have to use `unscoped` every time you want to access your `Crew` model without including `:pool` and `leader`.

```
Crew.unscoped.where(id: [1,2,4])
```

Comment: Not ideal not even useful in most cases, because rails_admin is for ADMINS only, and there a lot of other users than admins. So, yeah not ideal. Anyway, thanks for the info